# Is it possible to show hidden folders in a default FolderBrowserDialog?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using a System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog to let a user select a location.
The default location the user may override is located in %appdata%.

As long as the user is somewhere below %appdata% (the dialog opens at the currently set location, so per default the one below "AppData"), he can see and chose "Local", "LocalLow" and "Roaming", which are usually hidden like the "AppData" folder itself.

I do not want to touch Windows settings for showing hidden files etc.
but I do not find any property that will let me show all hidden files/folders by default.

What am I missing?

(I already took a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx))

I added some screenshots:

Hidden folders are visible as the initial directory was "Local":
[image: Hidden folders visible]

Hidden folders are NOT visible:
[image: Hidden folders are not visible]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control respects the user's settings. So, if you won't change the user's settings, and you are right to resist the temptation to do so, then hidden folders will not be shown.

Comment: thank you for your answer - I am still hoping for some kind of hack or workaround.

Comment: If the user wants to see hidden folders, they can ask for them to be shown. That would appear to be the obvious solution.

Answer (score 2):

An almost very dirty solution is to change the registry value of `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Hidden`
while loading your window and restore it to the previous value when you close it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but I do not want to touch Windows settings. If, for some reason, the application will crash while I perform this, I have altered the user's environment. Also, the application will be run with restricted rights, so I might not be allowed to perform this action after all.
Anyway, this might help others, so +1

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the FolderBrowserDialog, you could allow the user to type a path into a TextBox or ComboBox. While autocomplete won't show system or hidden folders, opening a FolderBrowserDialog with a hidden or system folder as its SelectedPath will then display the folder and its subfolders in the dialog.